# How do I create a BaseTest class for pytest

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, pytest

I am trying to create a class that will be inherited by all my other test classes. I seem to have a misunderstanding on how to go about it because when I try and run pytest it cant find my tests and throws an Empty suite error.

This is what I have now. Note this is for web ui testing using Selenium

base_test.py:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('chrome_driver_init')
class BaseTest:
        def __init__(self):
                self.login_page = LoginPage(self.driver)
                self.home_page = HomePage(self.driver)
                self.details_page = DetailsPage(self.driver)
```

I just want this to create instances of my Web Page Objects to be used by my Test Classes

test_login.py

```
class TestLogin(BaseTest):
    def test_login(self):
        self.login_page.login()
        assert 'Login Succesfull' in self.home_page.welcome_text()
```

`welcome_text()` is a simple method that finds a web element and returns its text

and finally just to be through my conftest.py:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def chrome_driver_init(request):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts, executable_path=ChromeDriverManager(path=TEST_PATH).install())
    request.cls.driver = driver
    driver.get(URL)
    driver.maximize_window()
    yield
    driver.quit()
```

I have a feelin that my BaseTest needs to inherit some pytest class and call `super().__init__()` but I cant find any documentaion or answers on the web to what that class would be.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

EDIT: As MrBean Suggested, I added self. to my page objects in BaseTest. Still get the same result though

Comment: Pytest doesn't need any base class in the test, so that should work in principle. I see that in your base class you forgot to put `self.` before the instance variables - please try to put an example there that will actually work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Added my page object initialization to my pytest fixture. No need for a BaseTest class. So my final code is

conftest.py

```
def page_object_init(request, driver):
    request.cls.login_page = LoginPage(driver)
    request.cls.home_page = HomePage(driver)
    request.cls.details_page = DetailsPage(driver)


@pytest.fixture()
def chrome_driver_init(request):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opts, executable_path=ChromeDriverManager(path=TEST_PATH).install())
    request.cls.driver = driver
    page_object_init(request, driver)
    driver.get(URL)
    driver.maximize_window()
    yield
    driver.quit()
```

test_login.py

```
class TestLogin():
    def test_login(self):
        self.login_page.login()
        assert 'Login Succesfull' in self.home_page.welcome_text()
```

Thanks to MrBean for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: it looks the `class TestLogin(BaseTest):` line should be updated to `class TestLogin():` as you mentioned, BaseTest is no longer required.

Answer (score 2):

So after some further digging it looks like pytest will not collect any test cases from classes that have a `__init__(self)` function. Only work around I was able to find was to declare the page objects at the beginning of every test. I find this very annoying and redundant. If anyone has a better solution please let me know.

Comment: I wasn't aware that `__init__` prevents tests to be collected, but you can just change it into an `autouse` fixture (_not_ named `__init__`), and it should work.